# Perform action in all of active tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

By this code:

```
chrome.tabs.query({},function(tabs){     
    tabs.forEach(function(tab){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: "document.body.style.background = 'red'"});
    });
});
```

is possible to change current tab bg-color.

but what i shoud to do if i want to change bg-color of all other active tab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code *is* attempting to apply this to all tabs, since you supplied an empty query: `{}`

This may be a permission problem if you don't get the intended result. To execute code in a tab through `executeScript`, you [need host permissions for the tab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi). So you need to add `"<all_urls>"` to your permissions to be able to do that.

The `"activeTab"` permission, for example, would grant you permission for the current active tab, but not others, so it's not suitable for this case.

Comment: Yep, problem was absence "<all_urls>" permission. thank you Xan.